# Ajax site not working on non www version of site

Tags: ajax, web-applications

A webapp I'm developing (@ www.PureRGB.com ) appears to load correctly both for the www and non-www urls for the site. However it appears ajax calls are not working correctly for the non-www version of the site. At least I think it might be related to ajax? The issue is apparent when you interact with some of the checkboxes (e.g. "E6-C41 cross processing" checkbox) on my webapp for the non-www url.

Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

Many thanks

Comment: Are the AJAX calls to the `www` domain? If so, it's possible you're hitting AJAX safeguards set to avoid cross-domain scripting when your AJAX requests happen from `foo.com` and go to `www.foo.com`.

Comment: Why don't simply make a redirect from the non-www to the www? It looks nicer and has lots of extra advantages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to hit `http://www.purergb.com/cmd_dispatch.php` when you click on that checkbox, so the request is blocked by the browser due to being cross-domain.  Remove the entire domain from that request (i.e. just hit `/cmd_dispatch.php` instead).

Comment: Removing the "www" would cause the "www" zone to fail. It would be better to use absolute paths instead of URIs in the requests, ie `/cmd_dispatch.php`

Comment: @Phil - +1, should have phrased that better.

Comment: Super! thats fixed it - great and unbelievably speedy answer!